# Can I use two useEffect and have map inside a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and would like some help with the following problem. I current have this code.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function FetchData() {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.github.com/orgs/org_name/repos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setRepos(data);
      })
      .then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
      {repos.map((repo) => (
        <div key={repo.id}>
          <div>
            <h2>Name: {repo.name}</h2>
            <p>Top 5 Contributors</p>
))}
```

My above codes work fine, but my problem now is that I would like to add the top 5 contributors to the repository and to access that I have to go to `https://api.github.com/repos/org_name/{repos}/contributors`, and to get to that, I first have to use `repo.contributor_url`  Should I use another `useEffect` and `map` to show the top 5 contributors?

Edit 
Basically I want to do something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${repos.contributors_url}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setContributors(data);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
...
<p> Top 5 Contributors: </p>
 <ul>
   {contributors.map((c, i) => {
   <li key={i}>{c.name}</li>
   )}
 </ul>
```

Comment: If it's a separate API request and separate set of data, then yes you can have a different state value and effect for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to React. React used to have class based components to handle state and those class based components had special functions called- **Life-Cycle-Methods**. But from **React 16.8** onwards React Community came up with **React-Hooks** and functional components can now be used to handle state and **useState() and useEffect()** are examples of Hooks.

Now **useEffect()** alone is used to do perform life-cycle method's work.

The way you have used **useEffect()** in your code is simulating **componentDidMount()** as you have kept the 2nd argument as an empty array **[]**

We can use other life-cycle methods like **componentDidUpdate()** and **componetnWillUnmount()** using **useEffect()** Hook itself.

***Then based on your requirement you can use useEffect() Hook as many times as required by your Component.***

**Coming to Updated part of your question now:**

So, you basically need to do **promise chaining**. We know that **fetch()** is promise based,so when one asynchronous call is resolved and we get the first data, within your **useEffect()** hook only, you need to make another asynchronous request using the second url-end point to get the respective data.

**Here is the updated code now: Try this**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FetchData() {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const [contributors, setContributors] = useState([]);
  const [isContributorLoading, setIsContributorLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setRepos(data); // Data 1(repos) is received
        // Now We make another API call to get Data 2 (contributors)
        return fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repos}/contributors');
      })
      .then((res) => res.json()) // Chaining promise,handling 2nd Fetch request
      .then((data2) => {
        console.log(data2);
        setContributors(data2);
       })
      .then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      { repos.length && repos.map((repo) => (
        <div key={repo.id}>
          <div>
            <h2>Name: {repo.name}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      <p> Top 5 Contributors: </p>
         <ul>
           {contributors.length && contributors.map((c, i) => {
             return <li key={i}>{c.name}</li>
           )}
          </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, basically you need to learn a bit more about how to use Hooks especially **useEffect()**, for now. Do some googling stuff, It would not be good if I tell you everything now. Give it a shot then.

Comment: @Lashan Fernando : I have approved your edit. Keep it up. I had however deliberately kept code like before, because we have no idea about how Khoo Wing Hang wants to implement it. :) Anyways good edit. Keep it up

Comment: @Khoo Wing Hang: Is your problem resolved bro, If not let me know what you actually are trying to achieve. I will surely get it done for you :)

Comment: I added an edit of what I want to do. Hopefully, it makes sense.

Comment: The `https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repos}/contributors` link is in `repos.contributors_url`. Can I use `fetch('${repos.contributors_url}'` or do I have to use something else?

Comment: Dear @Khoo Wing Hang : Your scenario is to make Asynchronous calls in order one after the another. Where the 2nd API call depends on the result fetched from first API call. So yes indeed you have to this thing only. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried to use your method of chaining promise, using `return fetch('${repos.contributors_url}')` but I get a syntax error saying `unexpected  token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: I think you are just close to getting it done now. Do one thing, First check your data coming from first API call. console.log(repos.contributors_url), see whether that is a proper url-end point. Just share with me. :)

Comment: when I do `console.log(repos.contributors_url)` i get `undefined`. But when i do `console.log(repos[0].contributors_url)` I get an array.

Comment: See, that is the problem. your url-end point is not correct with repos.contributors_url. And what about repos[0].contributors_url. I would suggest you to make a http request with fetch(repos[0].contributors_url) instead and hopefully you will get your contributors. By the way do you know why this error "unexpected  token < in JSON at position 0" came. In normal circumstances it comes when our JSON data has some typos or some missing double quotes. But this also comes when URL-End point is not valid, as is happening in your case.

Comment: When I do `return fetch(repos[0].contributors_url)` and `console.log(data2)` I get an array. So I assume that's a good thing.

Comment: @Khoo Wing Hang: It's not about assuming what is good and what is not my dear :) It's all about how the APIs have been implemented and what is the requirement. In many scenarios (as in your's), our data to be used depends on the result coming from another API. For instance, I have my weather app hosted at https://imran-weather-app.netlify.app/ and am making use of 2 APIs from accuWeather. Check the code from my github repo https://github.com/emmeiwhite/emmeiWeatherApp. You will learn a lot. Do also approve my answer as this is the solution (if you have previledges :))  Thank you

Comment: So in my case what should my second fetch request be? I can't just use `repos[0].contributors_url`, but `repos.contributors_url` is not working

Comment: Can you do one thing, write you components here https://repl.it/languages/reactjs Share code with me on my email emmeiwhite@gmail.com, I will do it for you :) I do however believe that you learned couple of good things from here @Khoo. Net Ninja is a youtube channel, you can learn loads of things from the instructor for free. Do learn from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcQyJ-gxke0 . Happy coding

Comment: I added the components to that link you sent and shared it with you already.

Comment: @KhooWingHang Yes dear friend I saw that, repl.io wasn't running the project. I have created a new project, will copy Components and run it locally now. Have been a bit occupied throughout the day. Will surely give it a shot once I get time. Don't worry. I will make it work for sure :)

Answer (score -1):

You can directly call apis inside one useEffect.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);
  const [contributor, setContributor] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
async function caller() {
  try {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos"
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    const contri = [];
    console.log(result);
    result.forEach((item) => {
      contri.push(fetch(`${item.contributors_url}`));
    });

    Promise.all(contri)
      .then((contributorResults) => contributorResults)
      .then((responses) => {
        console.log(responses);
        return Promise.all(responses.map((r) => r.json()));
      })
      .then((cont) => {
        setContributor([...cont])
      });

    setRepos(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
}
caller();
  }, []);

  return (
<div>
  {repos.map((repo,index) => (
    <div key={repo.id}>
      <h2> Name: {repo.name} </h2>
    
     {  contributor[`${index}`] && contributor[`${index}`].slice(0,5).map(item => {
        return <div key={item.id}>
            <div>{item.login}</div>
          </div>
     })}
     </div>
  ))}
  {isLoading && <div>...loading</div>}
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but to get `https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repos}/contributors` I first have to get from the first fetch request.

Comment: I think using `useEffect(async()` gives a warning to not use `async`?

Comment: @KhooWingHang - you want to fetch top 5 contibutor for each repo as first call will provide you all repository ?

Comment: @dcangulo - No warning to use async.

Comment: You should not use async that way in useEffect. You will have to call/create an async function from within the useEffect. Have a look here for reference: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326

Comment: @deepak yes, I can only get the contributors after the first fetch request. so my second fetch request has to be something like ``https://api.github.com/repos/org_name/${repos}/contributors``

Comment: @KhooWingHang - updated the code and you can test also.